# Javascript - Creating Faded Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I encounter the following problem: how can I create a stacked bar chart that can hold 3 variables only. **`(x, y, z)`** and `x + y + z = 100%`.

What's important is how can I make the colors edges between x y and y z of the bars faded as shown in the figure below? (Any popular library can be used)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single linear gradient in css with four percentage locations to achieve the desired result. You don't need to specify the 0% and 100% colors, but you do need to start and end the fades a few percentage points on either side or you'll get a hard color change. Here's a function that will help you center the labels too, but it doesn't handle validation or edge cases.

```js
function updateGradientBar(agree, depends, disagree) {

  let
   padding = 3,
    agreeFadeStart = agree - padding,
    dependsFadeStart = agree + padding,
    dependsFadeEnd = agree + depends - padding,
    disagreeFadeStart = agree + depends + padding,

    labelAgree = $('#gradient-bar .label.agree'),
    agreeLabelPosition = agree / 2,

    labelDepends = $('#gradient-bar .label.depends'),
    dependsLabelPosition = agree + (depends / 2),

    labelDisagree = $('#gradient-bar .label.disagree'),
    disgreeLabelPosition = agree + depends + (disagree / 2);


  $('#gradient-bar').css(
    'background',
    'linear-gradient(to right, green ' + agreeFadeStart + '%,' + 'orange ' + dependsFadeStart + '%, orange ' + dependsFadeEnd + '%,' + 'red ' + disagreeFadeStart + '%)');


  labelAgree.css('left', agreeLabelPosition + '%').text(agree + '%');
  labelDepends.css('left', dependsLabelPosition + '%').text(depends + '%');
  labelDisagree.css('left', disgreeLabelPosition + '%').text(disagree + '%');

}

updateGradientBar(35, 40, 25);
```

```css
#gradient-bar {
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#gradient-bar .label {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gradient-bar">
  <div class="label agree"></div>
  <div class="label depends"></div>
  <div class="label disagree"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a static solution for that using CSS:
You only have to "replace" the % unities with the appropriate values using javascript (this will not be a big deal).
The Solution: first: there is no possiblity to intersect colors in pure css. so I added to absolute positioned divs on the bar with a background color containing transparency.
HTML:

```
<div class="bar">
  <div class="agree">
    20%
  </div>
  <div class="seperator part1">

  </div>
  <div class="independants">
     30%
  </div>
  <div class="seperator part2">

  </div>
  <div class="disagree">
     50%
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.bar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.bar > div {
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.agree {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  background: green;
}

.independants {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  background: orange;
}
.disagree {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  background: red;
}

.seperator {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  z-index: 20;
}
.part1 {
  left: 16%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(122,188,255,0) 0%,rgba(249,186,97,0.44) 44%,rgba(237,176,64,1) 100%);
}
.part2 {
  left: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,164,28,1) 0%,rgba(249,186,97,0.56) 44%,rgba(237,176,64,0) 100%);
}
```

Check out the Fiddle for it  here: https://jsfiddle.net/taxostd0/5/